# replace data in xml file using python

Tags: xml, python-2.7, minidom

I have a xml file which has a path name which i would want to replace by  another path name.My xml looks like below

```
<company>
 <name>comp_name</name>
  <path><Pre-recorded>False</Pre-recorded>
   <wfmpath>'C:\Users\Public\wfm.csv'</wfmpath>          
      </path> 
</company>
```

when Pre-recorded is False, wfmpath should change to 'c:\Users\Public\my_wfm.csv'

I tried with this,but did not succeed!Please suggest

```
def readwfmpath(self,path):
    doc = minidom.parse("configurations.xml")
    #name = doc.getElementsByTagName("name")[0]
    staff = doc.getElementsByTagName("Pre-recorded")[0].firstChild.data
    if staff == "True":
        wfmpath = doc.getElementsByTagName("wfmpath")[0].firstChild.data
    else:
        wfmpath = doc.getElementsByTagName("wfmpath")[0].firstChild.data
        wfmpath.replaceChild(path)
    return wfmpath
```